# vue.jsの日本語ドキュメントをローカルで実行しようとするができない

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

Vue.jsの日本語ドキュメントをローカルで実行したいのですがうまくできません。
[ここのREADME](https://github.com/vuejs/jp.vuejs.org)に書いてあるのを参考に下記のコマンドを実行しましたが,`localhost:4000`にアクセスしてもドキュメントの内容が表示されません。
npm installの時にERRORが発生しており、git cloneがうまくできていないようですが、どうすれば解決するのでしょうか?

```
$ npm install -g hexo-cli
$ npm install -g hexo-server --save # https://hexo.io/docs/server.htmlによるとhexo serverは別になったらしい
$ npm install
$ hexo server
```

npm install時のError

```
npm WARN deprecated textlint-plugin-jtf-style@0.8.9: Use textlint-rule-preset-jtf-style. See https://github.com/azu/textlint-rule-preset-JTF-style/releases/tag/2.0.0
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508: Cloning into bare repository '/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508: 
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Darwin 15.2.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git /Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/Users/username/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-vuejs-jp-textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs-git-5e1819f931c8b509fa627bfa1bb41508'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/vue/jp.vuejs.org/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

githubへのsshアクセスに失敗しています。
githubのアカウントを作って公開鍵を登録するか、`package.json`を編集して

```
"textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs": "git@github.com:vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git"
```

を

```
"textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs": "https://github.com/vuejs-jp/textlint-checker-for-vuejs-jp-docs.git"
```

に変更すれば解決すると思います。